# Simulate incoming message notification

Tags: javascript, jquery

This ones kind of tough to explain..

I am trying to notify a user that a 'message' is being 'typed'. However it's a preset message from a parameter within a function.

Seeing as how the message(s) is/are preset I am trying to proportionally scale the 'incoming message animation' and message delay time based on the length of the 'message' being passed in the function to simulate a user typing on the other end (it wouldn't make sense for a 3 sentence message to appear instantly and it wouldn't make sense for a 3 worded message to appear after 30 seconds)

I've included a fiddle to better illustrate what I am aiming for... right now it only checks if the message has a length of 24 characters; the 'else if' is currently a place holder for what I am trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/ducFh/1/

jquery

```
function communicate(dialog) {
    if (dialog.length === 24) {
        messageIcon(3);
        setTimeout(function() {
            callExample(dialog);
        }, 2500);
    } else if (dialog.length > 24) {
        alert('oops');
    }
}

function messageIcon(time) {
    $('#infoBox').append("<span class='icon'>...</span>");
    for (i=0;i<time;i++) {
        $('.icon').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.icon').fadeOut('slow');
        if (i === time) {
            $('#infoBox .icon').remove();           
        }
    }
}

function callExample(message) {
    $('#infoBox').append("<span>example &gt; "+message+"</span>");
}

communicate("this is only an example.");
```

Comment: You might need a switch statement if you really want it to accurately portray the time it takes to type the message.  5-10 words maybe 5 seconds, 20 words maybe 10 seconds, etc etc etc.   Anything less fine will be less realistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploit the fact that JS is a functional language. JQuery Animations call a callback function, when the animation has finished ([.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)).

My approach (to make sure that the message never appears when the icon is visible) is to couple the waiting icon and the displaying of the message together, by showing the message *after* the icon flashed enoughly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ducFh/2/

```
function communicate(dialog) {

    // dividing by 8 because the icon was flashed 3
    // times in original code for a 24 character message.
    // But really this can be anything you want. Anything ;-)
    var iterations = dialog.length / 8;

    $('#infoBox').append("<span class='icon'>...</span>");

    // This method just makes the next method easier to read
    // It flashes the given jQuery selection once and then
    // calls the callback
    function fadeInThenOut(jq, callback) {
        jq.fadeIn('fast', function () {
            jq.fadeOut('slow', callback);
        });
    }

    // This function flashes the icon `iterationsToCome`-times
    // After it has finished it calls the callback.
    // Recursion is used to make this thing asynchronous (required
    // by the use of jQuery animations).
    function flashIcon(iterationsToCome, callback) {
        fadeInThenOut($('.icon'), function () {
            // classic pattern of recursive functions
            if (iterationsToCome > 0) {
                flashIcon(iterationsToCome - 1, callback);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }

    flashIcon(iterations, function () {
        $('#infoBox .icon').remove();

        // provoke some additional delay for the last
        // wait. could also be removed, and the append()
        // called immediately.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#infoBox').append("<span>example &gt; " + dialog + "</span>");
        }, 100);
    });
}

communicate("this is only an example.");
```

Note that I'm making heavy use of function-based scoping of variables and closures. If you don't know about this you should grab a good book on JavaScript ;-) Of course, if you have any questions about the code feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

What about multiplying a time by the length of the message? i.e. `setTimeout(..., 50 * dialog.length)` (number to adjust). In order to avoid insanely long times for long messages you can use a log function, i.e: `Math.round(Math.log(dialog.length) * ...)`